# In jsp file getting Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, veracode

below line showing veracode issue. If i use ESAPI methods jsonJSObj getting encripted.

```
var jsonJSObj = <%=((com.pag.policy.ui.forms.VehicleVinVerificationForm)request.getAttribute("vehicleVinVerificationForm")).getOnLoadJsonObject()%>
```

Comment: Don't know anything about veracode, but I bet it would help if you actually tell what the issue is, instead of calling it "veracode issue".

Comment: If we scan our application using veracode platform, it will give issues list those are different type of CWE issues. for this line it is showing high level issue